# Exclude columns in read.table() in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only read limited number of columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r)

I have a data text file with a million observations and 150 variable (v1 to v150) delimited by semicolons. I need only a selected handful of variables. Is there any way to read in only the variables I need? I am using `read.table("filepath/filename.txt", sep=";", header=T)`. If there is any other way than `read.table()` with which this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `help(read.table)` and particularly the `colClasses` argument.  Simply set the columns you want to ignore to `NULL` and they will be skipped.