# read.csv() - two out of three columns

Tags: r, read.csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only read limited number of columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r)

I have a ascii-dataset which consists of three columns, but only the last two are actual data. Now I want to dotchart the data by using `read.csv(file = "result1", sep= " ")`. R reads all three columns. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `colClasses` argument to skip columns:

```
mydata <- read.csv('mydata.csv', colClasses=c('NULL',NA,NA))
```

or

```
mydata <- read.csv('mydata.csv', colClasses=c('NULL', 'numeric', 'numeric'))
```