# How to read a specific columns from a csv file using R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only read limited number of columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r)

How to read specific columns from a csv file? is there a way to specify columns by index or column name?

Comment: It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Comment: I bet this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a precise reference.

Comment: @Andrie, but the answer here is different.

Comment: @TomasT. The answer is to set `colClasses` to `NULL` for the columns you don't want.  That is the same answer provided in the linked question.