# How can you read a CSV file in R with different number of columns

Tags: r, csv, import, read.table, sparse-columns

I have a sparse data set, one whose number of columns vary in length, in a csv format.  Here is a sample of the file text.

```
12223, University
12227, bridge, Sky
12828, Sunset
13801, Ground
14853, Tranceamerica
14854, San Francisco
15595, shibuya, Shrine
16126, fog, San Francisco
16520, California, ocean, summer, golden gate, beach, San Francisco
```

When I use

```
read.csv("data.txt", header = F)
```

R will interpret the data set as having 3 columns because the size is determined from the first 5 rows.  Is there anyway to force r to put the data in more columns?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of columns in your data set?

Comment: Yes, the maximum number of columns is known

Comment: My intuition is that specifying the `colClasses` argument in `read.table` (with the max number of columns) in combination with `fill = TRUE` should read the file in.

Comment: @BlueMagister I thought so too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: could you make a dummy `data.frame` with 2 rows and the correct number of columns, and then `rbind` the text file to it?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Deep in the `?read.table` documentation there is the following:

> The number of data columns is determined by looking at the first five
>   lines of input (or the whole file if it has less than five lines), or
>   from the length of `col.names` if it is specified and is longer. This
>   could conceivably be wrong if `fill` or `blank.lines.skip are true`, so
>   specify `col.names` if necessary (as in the ‘Examples’).

Therefore, let's define `col.names` to be length X (where X is the max number of fields in your dataset), and set `fill = TRUE`:

```
dat <- textConnection("12223, University
12227, bridge, Sky
12828, Sunset
13801, Ground
14853, Tranceamerica
14854, San Francisco
15595, shibuya, Shrine
16126, fog, San Francisco
16520, California, ocean, summer, golden gate, beach, San Francisco")

read.table(dat, header = FALSE, sep = ",", 
  col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(7)), fill = TRUE)

     V1             V2             V3      V4           V5     V6             V7
1 12223     University                                                          
2 12227         bridge            Sky                                           
3 12828         Sunset                                                          
4 13801         Ground                                                          
5 14853  Tranceamerica                                                          
6 14854  San Francisco                                                          
7 15595        shibuya         Shrine                                           
8 16126            fog  San Francisco                                           
9 16520     California          ocean  summer  golden gate  beach  San Francisco
```

If the maximum number of fields is unknown, you can use the nifty utility function `count.fields` (which I found in the `read.table` example code):

```
count.fields(dat, sep = ',')
# [1] 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 7
max(count.fields(dat, sep = ','))
# [1] 7
```

Possibly helpful related reading: [Only read limited number of columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r)

Comment: This took me forever. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

You could read the data like this:

```
dat <- textConnection("12223, University
12227, bridge, Sky
12828, Sunset
13801, Ground
14853, Tranceamerica
14854, San Francisco
15595, shibuya, Shrine
16126, fog, San Francisco
16520, California, ocean, summer, golden gate, beach, San Francisco")

dat <- readLines(dat)
dat <- strsplit(dat, ",")
```

This results in a list.

Comment: The data set that I have is large.  I am looking for a solution without copying and pasting the contents of the file.  I know I can open the file in ruby and search for the largest amount of commas in a line and move that line to the first row. I could then then open the file in R and all would be solved, but I was hoping for a simple solution in R.

Comment: Well, obviously you would use a file connection (read `?connection`). But I don't have access to your file ...

Comment: @CompChemist Put your file object (`data.txt`) in place of `dat`. The `textConnection` was used to quickly read in your example file.

Answer (score 3):

This does seem to work (following @BlueMagister's suggestion):

```
tt <- read.table("~/Downloads/tmp.csv", fill=TRUE, header=FALSE, 
          sep=",", colClasses=c("numeric", rep("character", 6)))
names(tt) <- paste("V", 1:7, sep="")

     V1             V2             V3      V4           V5     V6             V7
1 12223     University                                                          
2 12227         bridge            Sky                                           
3 12828         Sunset                                                          
4 13801         Ground                                                          
5 14853  Tranceamerica                                                          
6 14854  San Francisco                                                          
7 15595        shibuya         Shrine                                           
8 16126            fog  San Francisco                                           
9 16520     California          ocean  summer  golden gate  beach  San Francisco
```

Comment: I've just tried again. This doesn't works if I use the `text` argument.

Comment: Aha.. so that was the reason.. good to know this difference! Thanks for writing back.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar challenge, but `count.fields` from Blue Magister´s answer didn't work, probably because commas inside fields conflicted with `sep=","`. In addition, number of columns varied from file to file. 
So I just defined excess `col.names` in `read.table`(100 was enough in my case) and then I used `which(!is.na())` to get rid of excess columns.

```
dat <- read.table("path/to/file.csv", col.names = paste("V",1:100), fill = T, sep = ",")
dat <- dat[,which(!is.na(dat[1,]))]
```

Comment: Brilliant!
You are a legend. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is a bit more dynamic..

```
readVariableWidthFile <- function(filePath){
  con <-file(filePath)
  lines<- readLines(con)
  close(con)
  slines <- strsplit(lines,",")
  colCount <- max(unlist(lapply(slines, length)))

  FileContent <- read.csv(filePath,
                        header = FALSE,
                        col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(colCount)),
                        fill = TRUE)
  return(FileContent)
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer. What does your answer add that the currently accepted answer does not?

Comment: I agree this is more dynamic as it allows you to loop through `csv`s and not need to specify your number of columns