# write and read.csv different number of columns

Tags: r

A strange problem with `write` and `read.csv`. I have ways to work around this but would be great if someone can identify what is going on.

I have code from someone else which dynamically creates a series of CSVs by appending new rows.  The problem is that `read.csv` appears to read the newly created csv inconsistently.

Dummy code example:

```
datfile <- "E:/temp.csv"
write(paste("Name","tempname",sep=","),datfile,1)
write(paste("VShort",50,sep=","),datfile,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short1",1,1,sep=","),datfile,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short2",0,2,sep=","),datfile,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short3",0,2,sep=","),datfile,1,append=T)
write(paste("Long",0,0.3,0.6,1,sep=","),datfile,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short4",2,0,sep=","),datfile,1,append=T)
read.csv(datfile,header=F,colClasses="character")
```

Seven rows of data written to CSV, but `read.csv` reads in 8 rows (`Long` is split over two rows). Eight rows and three columns read in.

The problem is fixed by opening temp.csv in Excel and saving. Then `read.csv` reads in the 7 lines appropriately.

The problem only appears to exist under certain conditions. For example, remove `Short 3` and there is no problem:

```
datfile2 <- "E:/temp2.csv"
write(paste("Name","tempname",sep=","),datfile2,1)
write(paste("VShort",50,sep=","),datfile2,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short1",1,1,sep=","),datfile2,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short2",0,2,sep=","),datfile2,1,append=T)
write(paste("Long",0,0.3,0.6,1,sep=","),datfile2,1,append=T)
write(paste("Short4",2,0,sep=","),datfile2,1,append=T)
read.csv(datfile2,header=F,colClasses="character")
```

Six rows and five columns are read in.

Any ideas what is going on here?

R version 3.2.4 Revised

Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the following in `?read.csv`:

> The number of data columns is determined by looking at the first five
>   lines of input (or the whole file if it has less than five lines), or
>   from the length of col.names if it is specified and is longer. This
>   could conceivably be wrong if fill or blank.lines.skip are true, so
>   specify col.names if necessary (as in the ‘Examples’).

It just happens that the row with the most number of columns is the sixth row in your first example.

I suggest using `col.names` to get around this, e.g.:

```
`... read.csv(..., col.names = paste0('V', 1:6))`
```

---

As the OP notes in a comment to this answer, you can find out the number of 
columns required using `readLines`:

```
Ncol <- max(unlist(lapply(strsplit(readLines(datfile), ","), length)))
```

and then modify the above to give:

```
read.csv(datfile,header=F,colClasses="character", col.names=paste0("V", 1:Ncol))
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. Shows again that a careful read of the help material would have answered the question. I'll give col.names a go, but the number of columns is not fixed so may not be straightforward.

Comment: I ended up using: `Ncol <- max(unlist(lapply(strsplit(readLines(datfile), ","), length)))` and `read.csv(datfile,header=F,colClasses="character", col.names=paste0("V", 1:Ncol))`.   I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922493/how-can-you-read-a-csv-file-in-r-with-different-number-of-columns) helpful as well