# Importing a huge csv file while fread doesn't work in R

Tags: r, csv, data.table, readr

I want to import a big csv file in R (approximately 14 million rows and 13 columns). So I tried to use fread with the following code :

```
my_data <- fread(my_file,
                 sep = ";",
                 header = TRUE,
                 na.strings=c(""," ","NA"),
                 quote = "",
                 fill = TRUE,
                 check.names=FALSE,
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

However, I got the following error :

```
Error in fread(path_alertes_profil, sep = ";", header = TRUE, na.strings = c("",  : 
  Expecting 13 cols, but line 18533 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=';' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.
```

Therefore I tried to import my file with the function `read_delim` from the `readr` package, with the same parameters. It worked since my file appeared in the global environment (I'm working with RStudio). However, it only got 741629 rows instead of the 14+ million rows

How can I solve this problem (I tried to find a solution for the error when using `fread()` but didn't find any useful resource)

Comment: Did you try without specifying a separator? Regardless, I don't like that `my_data <- test <- as.data.frame(`. Why would you run `as.data.frame` and why would do copy the same data to two data sets?

Comment: My bad, especially with the `my_data <- test <- as.data.frame(` I modified the question (it isn't like that in my code I made an error while writing the quesiton). I did try without specifying a separator and got the same error message

Comment: Well, did you check out the row from the error message?

Comment: I think this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714323/r-error-text-after-processing-all-cols-in-fread-data-table/44715042#44715042

Comment: Yes ; it is due to some special characters that make the number of column from the corresponding rows goes from 13 to 14 (for instance in line 18533 I think the characters `&#` are the reasons of why I have the error message. However, it doesn't seem like all errors are due to the same characters, which makes it complicated for me. `read_delim` was pretty useful for me since it said where the parsing failed, so I could delete the annoying rows afterwards because I don't really care of hundreds of errors in my file of 14+ million rows

Comment: you could add a header so as to make the number of columns 14 and then you could use `fill=TRUE` within `fread`. Then you just delete the 14th column.

Comment: Try perhaps printing this line and check it out in console. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191364/quick-unix-command-to-display-specific-lines-in-the-middle-of-a-file), for instance.