# How to read a sparse CSV (with unequal number of items in each row) into R

Tags: r, dplyr

My CSV consists of rows with unequal number of items.
Eg.

```
Customer1, 01XX, 02XY, 05XYZ, 100XYZ, 03X23
Customer2, 02XX, 012X, 05XYZ
Customer3, 01XX, 02XY, 05XYZ, 012X, 005XZZ, 100XYZ
```

etc.

How to read such data from csv into an R object so that it could be referenced by the first item in CSV row, Customer_x, so that it can be used similar to df, be parametrised, something like:

```
myVector <- myCSVdata[CustomerID]
myVector
[1] 02XX, 012X, 05XYZ
```

EDIT: why minuses? How to correct? Maybe there is a more effective way than read csv when rows are unequal. Maybe a list of vectors? I am not sure.

EDIT2: I am trying at self-moderation: found a question worded differently for similar thing and an answer that generates a list of vectors, will experiment with that too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922750/3480717

Answer (score 4):

I like using `data.table::fread` to read txt/csv files.

I copied and pasted your example data to csv file and Imported it.
Notice that I set `header = FALSE`, as it seems that you don't have header.

```
df <- data.table::fread("Test.csv", header = FALSE)
df
```

Results

```
          V1   V2   V3    V4     V5     V6     V7
1: Customer1 01XX 02XY 05XYZ 100XYZ  03X23       
2: Customer2 02XX 012X 05XYZ                     
3: Customer3 01XX 02XY 05XYZ   012X 005XZZ 100XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to read in the data, you need to set the appropriate `read.table` arguments' values.

```
myCSVdata <- read.table(text = "
Customer1, 01XX, 02XY, 05XYZ, 100XYZ, 03X23
Customer2, 02XX, 012X, 05XYZ
Customer3, 01XX, 02XY, 05XYZ, 012X, 005XZZ, 100XYZ
", header = FALSE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

row.names(myCSVdata) <- myCSVdata[[1]]
myCSVdata[1] <- NULL
myCSVdata
#             V2    V3     V4      V5      V6      V7
#Customer1  01XX  02XY  05XYZ  100XYZ   03X23        
#Customer2  02XX  012X  05XYZ                        
#Customer3  01XX  02XY  05XYZ    012X  005XZZ  100XYZ
```

Then, it is just a matter of subsetting data frames.

```
myVector <- unlist(myCSVdata["Customer2", ])
myVector
#      V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7 
# " 02XX"  " 012X" " 05XYZ"       ""       ""       ""

unname(myVector)
#[1] " 02XX"  " 012X"  " 05XYZ" ""       ""       ""
```