# How to pull in a unbalanced csv file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a csv that is a few data frames appended to each other. However each data frame has different amount of columns. I would like to be able to either a) import the whole csv as a data frame in R or b) filter the CSV for specific rows before pulling it into R.

```
Type    Field1 Values
Fruits  Name   Size
Fruits  Orange Large
Fruits  Grape  Small
Shoes   Brand  Colour Price  Gender
Shoes   Nike   Blue   $100   Male
Shoes   Adidas Black  $80    Female
```

In the data frame above there are 2 data frames appended. One that is related to fruits and one that is related to shoes. I would like to pull all the data as a csv in R. Also assume I dont know the amount of columns there are in the csv

In R I would like the data frame to look like this

```
V1      V2     V3     V4     V5
Type    Field1 Values
Fruits  Name   Size
Fruits  Orange Large
Fruits  Grape  Small
Shoes   Brand  Colour Price  Gender
Shoes   Nike   Blue   $100   Male
Shoes   Adidas Black  $80    Female
```

Below is picture of real data. It is a csv file
[image]

I downloaded the file as  "csv" and when i look at the properties of the data it is a CSV. [image]

Edit* This code chuck actually does the job however, the number of columns needs to be known

```
read.table("pathtocsv.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",", 
  col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(5)), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: That looks like a fixed-width table, not CSV. Is that the raw file contents, or what you hope it may look like eventually in R?

Comment: Editing right now with what i want it to look like but that dataframe is what it currently looks like. It is a csv file.

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. The file you show has no commas, so it is not a CSV even if it is labeled as such. So we should check again to make sure we're answering the right question, is that exactly what data file looks like?

Comment: @GregorThomas the file is a csv i added the properties to the data frame above. When i downloaded it from interactive brokers it was also downloaded as a csv

Comment: A filename ending in `.csv` does not *make* it a CSV file. Just because Excel opens it does not *make* it a CSV file, Excel can open other formats too. It doesn't matter that the OS/interface is telling you `Type: Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values ...`, it says that because the filename ends in `.csv`, not because windows has an intrinsic knowledge of the contents of the file.

Comment: I found a solution. I am going to post below let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Does it get you all of the columns you need? If so, I think my (our) thoughts are relatively moot. The code looks fine (I just learned about the `count.fields` function, btw ... nice).

Comment: it works great @r2evans! thank you very much for yours and Gregors help

Comment: (Not sure I *helped*, but glad you found what you needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this post on SO [How can you read a CSV file in R with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922493/how-can-you-read-a-csv-file-in-r-with-different-number-of-columns)

```
path = "MyPath.csv"

columnNum = max(count.fields(path, sep = ','))

df =  read.table(path, header = FALSE, sep = ",", 
           col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(columnNum)), fill = TRUE)
```

This worked fine

Comment: Glad it worked. Guess the file has commas in it after all!