# How to read specific columns of a CSV when given the header as a vector

Tags: r, csv, readr

I have a large CSV file without a header row, and the header is available to me as a vector. I want to use a subset of the columns of the file without loading the entire file. The subset of columns required are provided as a separate list.

*Edit: in this case, the column names provided in the header list are important. This MRE only has 4 column names, but the solution should work for a large dataset with pre-specified column names. The catch is that the column names are only provided externally, not as a header in the CSV file.*

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

```
header <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
subset <- c("D", "B")
```

So far I have been reading the data in the following manner, which gets me the result I want, but loads the entire file first.

```
# Setup

library(readr)

write.table(
  structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 5L, 9L), V2 = c(2L, 6L, 10L), V3 = c(3L, 7L, 11L), V4 = c(4L, 8L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)),
  file="sample-data.csv",
  row.names=FALSE,
  col.names=FALSE,
  sep=","
)

header <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
subset <- c("D", "B")

# Current approach

df1 <- read_csv(
  "sample-data.csv",
  col_names = header
)[subset]

df1
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      D     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     2
2     8     6
3    12    10
```

How can I get the same result without loading the entire file first?

Related questions

- [Only read selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5788117/21891079) includes the header in the first row.
- [Ways to read only select columns from a file into R? (A happy medium between `read.table` and `scan`?) [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193742/21891079) does not specify column names outside the file and the answers do not apply to this situation.
- [how to skip reading certain columns in readr [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31150351/21891079) is different because it seems to be about skipping an unknown first column and reading a known second and third column across multiple files. Data types are not necessarily known in advance in this question.
- [Is there a way to omit the first column when reading a csv [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14527466/21891079): column is skipped based on position, not position in an externally provided list of column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `readr::read_csv` with `col_names` and `col_select` arguments.

```r
header <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
subset <- c("D", "B")

readr::read_csv("sample_data.csv",
                col_names = header,
                col_select = any_of(subset))

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#       D     B
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4     2
# 2     8     6
# 3    12    10
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a reason to use `any_of` instead of `all_of`?

Comment: @JoshuaShew `all_of` is for strict selection. If some column name in `subset` do not exist in the imported data, you will get an error. `any_of()` is a conservative option to avoid errors. But in your case `any_of` or `all_of` are both okey!

Comment: Noted! This answer works best for me because the parameters use the `header` and `subset` variables instead of copy-pasting the values. The explanation for when to use `any_of()` vs `all_of()` was also helpful.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover When I set `col_names = header`, the column names A,B,C,D have been assigned to the data, so `col_select` consequently works. I think your suggestion is not correct here.

Answer (score 2):

**before OP edit about header**

You don't have to read the entire file in at once as there is an argument with the `read_csv()` function. You would just need to modify your code to

```
df1 <- read_csv(
  "sample-data.csv",
  col_select=c("D","B")
)
```

**After edit**

```
df1 <- read_csv(
  "c:/data/56791/originals/test.csv",
  col_names = c("A","B","C","D"),
  col_select = c(4,2)
)
```

if you give the arguments defined vectors like in the OPs question, you would need to follow Darren's answer using `any_of` or you will receive the warning message

```
Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `all_of()` or `any_of()` instead.
```

Important note:
`col_names=` has to be given a header the column length of the csv
file or you will get the error

```
! Names repair functions cant return `NA` values.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `read_csv` from the `readr`package you have the argument `col_select` where you can select the columns to read.

Answer (score 0):

The `readr::read_csv()` function has an argument called `col_select` that allows you to specify which columns to read using the same language as `dplyr::select()`. So in practice, this looks like:

```
df1 <- readr::read_csv(
  file = "sample-data.csv",
  col_names = header,
  col_select = c(D, B)
)
```

Which then gives the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      D     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     2
2     8     6
3    12    10
```

You can also call `attr(df1, "spec")` which confirms that columns `A` and `C` were skipped when reading the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping to pass the variable `subset` in as a the `col_select` parameter but I got the following warning: [FAQ - Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html). It seems that the approach here it to use `col_select  = all_of(subset)` instead.