# Loading files with fread

Tags: r

I'm trying to load only the 3rd column from all csv files in a folder. Each file has 20,000 rows and 4 columns, and I'd like to end up with a data frame of n (n = number or files; 6 in this case) columns and 20,000 rows. I tried using `colClasses` to specify the columns I want to load, but without success. Also, I can't get it to create n columns rather than 4 columns (where each column represents one variable found in the all of the files). I'm trying to get a 6 * 20,000 data frame where each column represents a specified variable from each file (the 3rd column from each file). Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe something like `rbindlist(sapply(files, fread, header=TRUE, nrows=r, select=3:5))`? With the `select` argument uou can choose which columns are loaded. You can also drop columns with the `drop` argument. See also [*"Only read limited number of columns in R"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r/33201353#33201353) and [*"Reading multiple files into R - Best practice"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/reading-multiple-files-into-r-best-practice/32888918#32888918) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `select` argument of `fread` for keeping columns, or `drop` to not read columns, not `colClasses`. (with `data.table 1.9.6`)

something like this :

```
ltab <- lapply(files, fread, header=TRUE, select = 3, nrows=r))
```

You should obtain a list of 6 tables of 20000 rows and 1 column

Then a `Tab <- do.call("cbind", ltab)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comment, you can use the `select` or `drop` arguments of `fread`.

An alternative solution is to read the files `sapply` and use `idcol` parameter of `rbindlist` to create an id-column. Next you reshape the dataset to wide format as follows (you will need [*data.table 1.9.7*](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for this):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(sapply(files, fread, header=TRUE, nrows=r, select=3), idcol = "id")
dcast(DT, rowid(id) ~ id, value.var="name-of-selected-column")
```

The result is a datatable with the used filenames as columnnames.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this does what I wanted to accomplish as well!