# R drop columns when reading from CSV before the column type is identified

Tags: r, csv, s

I have a fairly large data set and I would like to drop some columns before the column type / class is deduced.. How do I do this.

I tried this

```
Initial <- read.csv("file.csv",header = T,fill=T,nrows=100)
Classes <- sapply(initial,class)
Fullefileread <- read.csv("file.csv",colclasses = classes)
```

But this complains as some data 100k rows in is not null which was null In the 100 subset.

Comment: Nrows. This is specifying the number of rows to read. Changed this now

Comment: This is not exactly straightforward because R is going to read the whole file into memory anyway. All `colClasses` does is control what is returned by `read.csv()`, not what is actually read from disk.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r

Comment: try the `fread` function in `data.table` package. You can always convert back to a data frame if required. The benefit of `fread` is that it will change data types while reading if required.