# Subsetting columns not working correctly

Tags: r, data.table

I am running the following code:

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread("file location", colClasses = 'factor')
test <- test[1:100]
test[, c(1:5)]
```

I am trying to look at the first 100 observations and the first 5 columns, but when I run the second function the output is:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe show the structure? And then describe the expected output?

Comment: Or `head(test, 100)[, 1:5]`

Comment: here is my code that I used:

Comment: test <- fread("file location", colClasses = 'factor')

    test[1:100,1:5]

Comment: I am looking for an output of the first 100 observations and the first 5 columns.  I believe it has something to do with fread

Comment: `test[1:100, 1:5, with=FALSE]`

Comment: thanks! that was what i was looking for

Comment: what does the with command do in that function?

Comment: `fread` reads the data in and creates a `data.table` object. It behaves differently from data frames https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Comment: For reading a limited number of columns, see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r).