# Selecting specific columns with readr cols_only

Tags: r, readr

I'm working with a delim file that has no headers for the columns. There are 45 columns but I only want the first 26 of them. I can't quite figure out the right syntax for cols_only when dealing with multiple un-named columns. Where does the cols_only go given the code I have below?

```
ex <- read_delim("ex.txt", delim = ",", col_names = FALSE, skip = 4)
```

Comment: You could just use `read.delim` and specify the `colClasses` (`NULL` for columns you don't want to read)

Comment: See: [Only read limited number of columns in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r)