# Read certain columns if exist using read.csv.sql from sqldf

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have very large csv files (2.3 GB). I only want to read certain columns that could be or could not be there.

I am using the following code that was suggested here 
[Only read limited number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns)

```
library(sqldf) 
loc <- read.csv.sql("data.csv",
                    sql = "select locID, City, CRESTA, Latitude, Longitude from file",
                    sep = ",")
```

How can I deal with the situation when for example the column "City" is not in the csv?

Comment: Remove it from the `sql` statement? Or are you referring to how to detect that this column is missing?

Comment: Not detect, just skip it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds out which columns are available, intersects their names with the names of the columns that are wanted and only reads those.

```
library(sqldf)

nms_wanted <- c("locID", "City", "CRESTA", "Latitude", "Longitude")
nms_avail <- names(read.csv("data.csv", nrows = 0))
nms <- intersect(nms_avail, nms_wanted)
fn$read.csv.sql("data.csv", "select `toString(nms)` from file")
```