# Problems with binding columns from two data frames using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, naming, cbind

I have 7 of two different `asc` files loaded into R, `asc[i]` and `wasc[i]`, `[i]` denotes that there are 1:7 `ascs` and `wascs` loaded into R. I need to combine the `wasc[i]` with the `asc[i][[1]]` (Just the first column in `asc[i]` with the whole `wasc[i]` file).

This should be repeated for every pair of `asc` and `wasc` files.

The code keeps giving me blank data frames, so I don't know why this doesn't work. The naming is correct, yet the code is not recognizing that the `asc[i]` and `wasc[i]` correlate with previously loaded files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
# These data frames will reproduce my issue 

asc1 <- data.frame(x= c(rep("A.tif", 20)), y = 1:20)
wasc1 <- data.frame(x= c(rep("B.tif", 20)), y = c(rep("Imager",20)))

asc2 <- data.frame(x= c(rep("A.tif", 20)), y = 1:20)
wasc2 <- data.frame(x= c(rep("B.tif", 20)), y = c(rep("Imager",20)))

asc3 <- data.frame(x= c(rep("A.tif", 20)), y = 1:20)
wasc3 <- data.frame(x= c(rep("B.tif", 20)), y = c(rep("Imager",20)))


for (i in 1:3) {
      d <- paste("asc", i, sep ="")
      f <- paste("wasc", i, sep ="")
      full_wing <- as.character(paste("full_wing", i, sep = ""))
      assign(full_wing,cbind(d[[1]], f))
    }

# Output of full_wing1 data frame

dput(full_wing1)

structure(c("asc1", "wasc1"), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
c("", "f")))
```

Additional Information:

1. asc files are 19 columns long
2. wasc files are 13 columns long

I only want to combine column 1 from the `asc` file with the entire `wasc` file, thus cutting out the remaining 18 columns of the `asc` file.

Comment: Hi Connor, it would be great if you could prepare a reproducible example so we can cut and paste your code directly into our own R sessions, run it, and see what's going on. Sometimes this requires you preparing your data (or a representative subset of your data in the same format you are using) using `dput`. Thanks :)

Comment: @mysteRious I just added more background to my question. The code is producing an empty (2 column, 1 row) vector that is named properly but has NA's in place of actual data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: I would love to attach two sample asc's, but I do not know how to include that into the question @Tung. Do you have a specific function I can use?

Comment: @ConnorMurray: you can upload sample files to Google Drive, Dropbox or any other sites then add the links to your question

Comment: Using `cbind` in a `for` loop is indeed a problem, it's terribly inefficient. And working with sequentially named variables and `assign` is a real pain and potentially buggy, but putting them in a `list` works very well. See [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for a much much better way to do this, especially my answer.

Comment: Regarding the reproducible example, *we do not want files in Dropbox*, we want *small*, illustrative examples in the question itself. Tung gave you several links, the `reprex` and `datapasta` packages have their own functions, and in base R you can use `dput`. Or just share code to create a little data frame, like `wasc = data.frame(x = 1, y = 2)`.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry for the confusion everyone. I added some data frames that will reproduce the issues I am having. @Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# put data in a list
asc = mget(ls(pattern = "^asc"))
wasc = mget(ls(pattern = "^wasc"))

full_wing = Map(f = function(w, a) cbind(w, a[[1]]), w = wasc, a = asc)
```

`Map` is a nice shortcut for iterating in parallel over multiple arguments. It returns a nice `list`. You can access the individual elements with, e.g., `full_wing[[1]]`, `full_wing[[3]]`, etc. `Map` is just a shortcut, the above code is basically equivalent to the `for` loop below:

```
results = list()
for (i in seq_along(asc)) {
    results[[i]] = cbind(wasc[[i]], asc[[i]][[1]])
}
```

I use `mget` to put the data in a list because in your example you already have objects like `asc1`, `asc2`, etc. A much better way to go is to never create those variables in the first place, instead read the files directly into a list, something like this:

```
asc_paths = list.files(pattern = "^asc")
asc = lapply(asc_paths, read.table)
```

You can see a lot more explanation of this at [How to make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061)

If you only ever need one column of the `asc` files, another way to simplify this would be to only read in the needed column, see [Only read limited number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5788117/903061) for some recommendations there.