# Importing columns from .csv as a "character" type instead of integer in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a single column from a .csv file as a character in the same way that `id <- c("341432", "52312", "63432")` would do. However, when I do the following:

```
id <- idfromcsv[[1]]
```

R imports this as an integer when I try `typeof(id)`. How do I import a single column from a .csv in the exact same way that `id <- c("341432", "52312", "63432")` would do it?

Comment: this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-selected-columns

Comment: Use `readr::read_csv.`  It has a `col_types` argument that allows you to specify _character_.  Read `vignette("readr")` for details.

Comment: What is `idfromcsv` ?

Comment: @RonakShah `idfromcsv <- read.csv("patientidlist.csv")`, i.e. it's a `read.csv()` of the list of patient ID's of interest