# What is the most efficient read csv function / package in R at importing a subset of csv columns

Tags: r, csv, import, fread, readr

I am trying to load a csv into R that is c. 180k rows and c.9k columns. I only need a subset of c.100 columns, and know the names of the columns that I need.

The answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-selected-columns) cover a lot of the different options for selecting a subset of columns when importing a csv.

Using those answers, and my own knowledge, I have tried to use [read.csv](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table) and [read.table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table) from [utils](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2), [fread](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.13.2/topics/fread) from [data.table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.13.2), and [read_csv](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) from [readr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf). All of these functions seem to import the whole csv and then subset the columns - which is very inefficient where I only need such a small subset of columns. I have also tried to use [read.csv.sql](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-11/topics/read.csv.sql) from [sqldf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-11), which seemed promising as selecting specific columns is a very common SQL task, but I could not import a subset of columns because I got the error `Error: too many columns on file`.

Two contributions from the community that would really help me out:

1. Can anyone point to a different import function that would be a lot more efficient where I only need a subset of columns?
2. Can anyone give more context about how these functions work and correct my misunderstanding or reassure me that the solution I'm looking for doesn't exist?

Many thanks!

P.S. I haven't asked many questions on SO before so I'd appreciate feedback if I need to ask in a different way.

Comment: If you know the columns you want to read in, is pre-processing the file an option? What is your OS?

Comment: "All of these functions seem to import the whole csv and then subset the columns - which is very inefficient where I only need such a small subset of columns." This isn't true. My experience is fread is the fastest.

Comment: Either `data.table::fread` or `vroom::vroom` should let you load specific columns without loading the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many command line utilities (e.g. sed, awk, cut, csvfix, miller, csvkit, csvtk) that can do this.  Below we use [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) ([releases](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv/releases)).  This removes the unwanted columns before the file ever reaches R.  Use the full path to xsv if iot is not already on the PATH.  `xsv` accepts column names as shown below or field numbers.

```
# write out test data
write.csv(iris, "iris-test.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

cmd <- "xsv select Sepal.Length,Petal.Length-Species iris-test.csv"
DF <- read.csv(pipe(cmd))

head(DF)
##   Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          4.6          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          5.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6          5.4          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Or with UNIX [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) (also available in Windows [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) in \Rtools40\usr\bin in R 4.0+) the following works.  Use the full path to `cut` if `cut` is not already on your `PATH`.

```
cmd2 <- "cut -d, -f 1,3-5 iris-test.csv"
DF <- read.csv(pipe(cmd2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. I keep `csv` files compressed in `zstd` format for better performance compared to `gzip`. If you use gzipped `csv` files just replace `zstd` with `gunzip` and adjust the command line options.

You need to keep the `zstd` binary downloaded from https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases and `csvtk` binary downloaded from https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/ in your system path.

Suppose you need to load only three columns, viz. YR_TA, MJH_CD, TV_TC_NO from a wide csv file (which also contains many other columns) into R while also specifying data types for the required columns.

The following code loads only specified columns from `csv` file into R and R won't even know about other columns present in the `csv` file.

```
library(data.table)
fyl <- "... path to your compressed csv file"

# define column data type specification for R
cols <- c(YR_TA="factor", MJH_CD="character", TV_TC_NO="character")

dt <- fread(cmd = paste("zstd -dcq", fyl, "| csvtk cut -f YR_TA,MJH_CD,TV_TC_NO"), select = cols)
```

Note that if the `csv` file is really huge for your computer RAM, selecting columns from within `fread` statement using `select` will cause low memory error because `fread` still needs to map the **entire `csv` file** in memory before selection. So it's better that `fread` sees only the required columns. Streaming only the required columns to `fread` using the external tool `csvtk` helps with that.