# Selecting non-consecutive columns in R tables

Tags: r

Let's say I have a some table, T. Assume T has 5 columns. I understand how to select any consecutive subset of columns and store them as a new table. For that I would use brackets and a colon to the right of a comma:

```
newT <- T[,2:4]   # creates newT from columns 2 through 4 in T
```

But how do I select non-consecutive columns for subsetting? Let's say I want to select Column 1 and Column 3? How do I go about doing this? Another type of selection I may want to do, and not sure how to, is selecting random columns from T.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to read only select columns from a file into R? (A happy medium between `read.table` and `scan`?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193742/ways-to-read-only-select-columns-from-a-file-into-r-a-happy-medium-between-re)

Comment: Naming objects 'T' (or 'F') can end up causing problems down the line -- it is better to avoid it.  Also there *are* "tables" in R, but I'm guessing that you really have a data frame or a matrix.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You simply first generate the indexes you want. The `c` function allows you to concatenate values. The values can be either column indices or column names (but not mixed).

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10))
cols <- c(1, 4:8, 10)
df[,cols]
```

You can also select which column indices to **remove** by specifying a negative index:

```
df[, -c(3, 5)] # all but the third and fifth columns
```

Comment: How to implement something like this?  `val <- 6  cols <- c(1, c(val-4:val-1))  df[,cols]`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you should try something similar to the following:

```
df1 = data.frame(state=c("KS","CO","CA","FL","CA"), value=c(1,2,3,7,9))
df1

df1[c(c(1,3),4:5),]
df1[c(1,3,4:5),]
```

Comment: I really like how concise your solution is, keeping it all in one command with the `c` function. However, your solution subsets on non-consecutive rows whereas the question above asks how to subset on non-consecutive columns, which, for the sample data frame `df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10))`, would look like this `df[,c(1,3,4:5)]`

Answer (score 2):

For random columns check out `?sample`

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(25), 5))
df
#         X1        X2         X3         X4        X5
#1 0.7973941 0.6142358 0.07211461 0.01478683 0.6623704
#2 0.8992845 0.8347466 0.54495115 0.52242817 0.4944838
#3 0.8695551 0.9228987 0.00838420 0.58049324 0.9256282
#4 0.1559048 0.7116077 0.08964883 0.06799828 0.3752833
#5 0.2179599 0.4533054 0.60817319 0.62235228 0.8357441

df[ ,sample(names(df), 3)]
#         X5         X3        X2
#1 0.6623704 0.07211461 0.6142358
#2 0.4944838 0.54495115 0.8347466
#3 0.9256282 0.00838420 0.9228987
#4 0.3752833 0.08964883 0.7116077
#5 0.8357441 0.60817319 0.4533054
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use logical values. Eg. `df[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)]` selects the first and third column. The logical vector must have a number or elements equal to the number of columns in the data frame, otherwise its elements are replicated up to the number of columns.