# Rename columns that are not together using colnames()

Tags: r, dataframe, names

Considering the simple code,

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:2,
                 y = 3:4,
                 z = 5:6)
```

How can I rename with one line columns `x` and `z` using `colnames()`?

I understand that `colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("p", "q")` would modify the first two headers, but how can I rename not-together columns?

I am aware of different commands that can do the job, just wondering if there is a `colnames()` solution.

Comment: `names(df)[c(1,3)] <- c("p", "q")` or `names(df)[match(c("x", "z"), names(df))] <- c("p", "q")`

Comment: `1:2` is really just shorthand for `c(1, 2)`. And you can put whatever column numbers  you want in `c()`.

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, you are right. I have thought that there exists already an old answer to this, but didn't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting non-consecutive columns in R tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174237/selecting-non-consecutive-columns-in-r-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `1:2`, which is selecting column 1 and column 2, you could use `c(1,3)` for column 1 and 3. Also I would use `names` for a `data.frame` instead of `colnames` but `colnames` would also work.

```
names(df)[c(1,3)] <- c("p", "q")
```

---

In case the positions are not known, but the names, you can use `match` to get the desired columns.

```
names(df)[match(c("x", "z"), names(df))] <- c("p", "q")
```

Or a more robust version in case a match is not found.

```
i <- c(x = "p", z = "q")[names(df)]
j <- !is.na(i)
names(df)[j] <- i[j]
```

Or a variant without using intermediate steps.

```
names(df) <- c(x = "p", z = "q", setNames(names(df), names(df)))[names(df)]

names(df) <- (\(.) c(x = "p", z = "q", setNames(., .))[.])(names(df)) #Variant
```

or using `transform`.

```
names(df) <- transform(as.list(setNames(names(df), names(df))), x="p", z="q")
```

Have also a look at [Rename multiple columns by names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20987295/10488504) and [Canonical tidyverse method to update some values of a vector from a look-up table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67081496/10488504).

---

Note: In the source of `colnames<-` you find the lines:

```
    if (is.data.frame(x)) {
        names(x) <- value
    }
```

So I prefer to use `names` instead of `colnames` when I have a `data.frame`.