# How to import only some columns from XLS with ETL?

Tags: etl, talend

I want to do something like [Read only certain columns from xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298800) in Jaspersoft ETL Express 5.4.1, but I don't know the schema of the files. However, from what I read [here](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=190513179), it looks like I can only do this with the Enterprise Version's Dynamic Schema thing.

Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using tMap component. design job like below.

```
tFileInputExcel--main--TMap---main--youroutput
```

1. create metadata for your input file that is excel
2. then used this metadata in your input component
3. in Tmap select only required columns in output.

See the image of tMap wherein i am selecting only two columns from input flow. 
[image]

Enterprise version has many features and dynamic schema is the most important one. But as far as your concern that is not required. it is required if you have variable of schema wherein you don`t know how many columns you will received in your feed.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted was just that, the ability to read Excel files without first knowing the incoming schema. I may not have articulated it well enough in the OP. I'll change that now.

Comment: In that case you have to use Dynamic schema feature in Talend subscription version.