# read a text file into R for selected variables based on their location in the file

Tags: r

I am trying to read a text file into R. I only want to import some selected variables. I know where they are located, say 15-18 are dob_yy, mob_mm is from 19 to 20. Anyway I can read such a file? 
In SAS,when I read a file, I could do the following
 input dob_yy 15-18 mob_mm 19-20 
Any similar method in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193742/ways-to-read-only-select-columns-from-a-file-into-r-a-happy-medium-between-re

Answer (score 2):

The package `data.table` contains the `fread` function which can be used as an alternative to the base function `read.table`. It takes an argument `select` which does what you want (from `?fread`):

```
  select: Vector of column names or numbers to keep, drop the rest.
```

So you would do `fread(..., select = c(15:18, 19:20))` (alternatively you can specify the variable names instead of positions).